# Java variable return type of function in enum

Tags: java, function, generics, enums

In an Enum I would like to associate a function to each element like:

```
public enum EleType {
    INTEGER(Integer.class,rand -> rand.nextInt()), 
    CHARACTER(Character.class, rand -> (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a'));

    private EleType(Class cl, Function<Random, ?> cr) { 
        this.classType = cl; 
        this.creator = cr;
    }
    public Class getClassType() { return classType; }
    public Function<Random, ?> getCreator() { return creator; }


    private final Class<?> classType;

    private final Function<Random, ?> creator;


}
```

The return type of the function (the question mark) should be the class of the respective element. So for `INTEGER`, the return type of the `Function` should be Integer and for `CHARACTER` it should be `Character`. How do I achieve this? If I leave it as it is with the questionmark and try to use it in `RandomList<Integer> randomList = new RandomList<>(eleType.getCreator(), 10);` where

```
public class RandomList<T> {

    private List<T> list;


    public List<T> getList() {
        return list;
    }


    public RandomList (Function<Random, T> creator, int n) {
        list = new ArrayList<T>();

        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
           list.add(creator.apply(rand));
        }
    }
}
```

I receive an error message:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `RandomList<capture#2-of ?>` to 
>        `RandomList<Integer>`
>   Cannot infer type arguments for `RandomList<>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, what you would like to do is give the enum a type parameter. Something conceptually like this; but this does not work, because enums cannot have type parameters:

```
// Not valid Java!
public enum EleType<T> {
    INTEGER(Integer.class, rand -> rand.nextInt()),
    CHARACTER(Character.class, rand -> (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a'));

    private final Class<T> classType;
    private final Function<Random, T> creator;

    // Constructor and getters
}
```

The wildcard does not work either. Note that the `?` means: a **specifc** but **unknown** type. A common misunderstanding that people have is that the wildcard means "any type", but that is not what it means. If you want "any type", use `Object` instead of `?` - but ofcourse that means you lose type information and type safety.

The most type-safe way to do this is by using a class with a type parameter and public static constants instead of an enum.

```
public final class EleType<T> {
    public static final EleType<Integer> INTEGER = new EleType<>(Integer.class,
            rand -> rand.nextInt());
    public static final EleType<Character> CHARACTER = new EleType<>(Character.class,
            rand -> (char) (rand.nextInt(26) + 'a'));

    private final Class<T> classType;
    private final Function<Random, T> creator;

    private EleType(Class<T> classType, Function<Random, T> creator) {
        this.classType = classType;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    // Getters
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant to write: `public static final EleType<Integer> INTEGER = new EleType<Integer>(Integer.class, rand -> rand.nextInt());` and similar for CHARACTER, correct?

Comment: How would I define a `values()` method similar to the one in `enum`?

Comment: You'd have to implement something like a `values()` method yourself; it could just return a fixed list of values, or it could find all the static final fields of the class through reflection.

Comment: Fixed the issue you mentioned in your first comment.

Comment: But what would be the return type of `values()`?

Comment: That's up to you, it could for example be `List<EleType<?>>`.

Comment: I created an example here: https://gist.github.com/jesperdj/0cdd610313d51ff1973f974afdb5a766